# Preventing div from overlapping (boostrap)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been trying to fix several overlapping divs. I've found the problem, but I do not know how to fix it.

Right now, I'm trying to create this animated dropdown box. However, when I duplicate this div, the original box and the new one overlap. This is due to the `position: absolute;` I've added for aesthetic purpose. Is there a way to work around this?

Also, I've created a dropdown animation using Javascript that targets the class `.faqInner` to display itself. Problem is, since I targeted a class, when the divs are duplicated, by pressing just one of the buttons, all the other divs show up. Is there a solution to this other than assigning each box an id, and animating them one by one?

My code in JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/docao248/wh7fzg61/1/

Answer (score 0):

Fixed jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wh7fzg61/22/

1) Since you're using position `absolute` on `.faqInner`, the parent container `.faqSectionSub` has no height and the items are stacked in one place. There seems to be no good reason to use absolute position to get the design you're aiming for, so I suggest you don't use it. I've restyled the layout slightly in the fiddle above as an option.

2) The callback function for click event has `this` content assigned to the current element. If you modify `$(".faqInner").slideToggle("slow")` to something like `$(this).parent().find('.faqInner').slideToggle('slow')`, the class will only be searched inside the clicked parent.